# TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 224), <f8 using PIL Image.fromarray()

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, python-imaging-library

This is my line of code:

```
cam_gb = Image.fromarray(cam_gb)
```

here,
`cam_gb` is of type `numpy.ndarray`, dtype `float64` and shape `(3, 224, 224)`. So when I run this, I get an error:

```
File "\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3073, in fromarray
raise TypeError(msg) from e
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 224), <f8
```

Even when I transpose `cam_gb` from shape `(3, 224, 224)` to `(224, 224, 3)`, I get the same error.

I also tried:

```
cam_gb = Image.fromarray(cam_gb.astype(np.uint8))
```

I got this error:

```
File "\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3073, in fromarray
raise TypeError(msg) from e
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 224), |u1
```

I also tried:

```
cam_gb = Image.fromarray((cam_gb * 255).astype(np.uint8))
```

but got this error:

```
File "\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3073, in fromarray
raise TypeError(msg) from e
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 224), |u1
```

please help.
Thanks

I wanted to try:

```
cam_gb_on_image = Image.alpha_composite(original_image, cam_gb)
```

Comment: You need to show us more code.  Where does `cam_gb` come from?  Why is it 1,1,224 if you think it should be 224x224?

Comment: Why does the title say `TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3)`, if the errors actually say `TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 224)`?

Comment: "Even when I transpose cam_gb from shape (3, 224, 224) to (224, 224, 3)" - what code did you use, in order to do this? Did you check the shape after transposing? Was it as you expected?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry its actually (1,1,224). I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your array have shape (224, 224, 3) and be of `dtype=np.uint8` for PIL to be able to understand it as an RGB image:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Make array (224, 224, 3) of rgb(255,128,0), i.e. orange
a = np.full((224,224,3), [255,128,0], np.uint8)

# Make PIL Image from Numpy array
Image.fromarray(a).save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

So, if `cam_gb` is of shape (3, 244, 244), you probably want:

```
a = np.transpose(cam_gb, (1, 2, 0))
```

Comment: You also need to consder the range of your data so you should state the value of  `cam_gb.min()` and `cam_gb.max()`